# Illustrator shows a faded color of the color I select

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Using Illustrator CC 2015.

I created a circle shape and the I select the fill color to be a bright red Red:255 G:0 B:0.

Problem is that the shown color of the circle is not red but a kind of orange.

I made sure that the circle:

- has Opacity: 100%
- the layer is at the very top of all other layers
- No masks

The Color Mode of the document is RGB

Capture: [image]

Comment: What does the appearance panel show, both for the object and the layer? What does it look like if you hide the yellow background? Also.. that isn't a circle.

Comment: In View>proof setup what is your working profile? (Illustrator setup working mode while creating file, changing it later don't affect it). 
Is any other field unchecked?

Answer (score 4):

That looks like:

1. You have got the object fill (circle / square) set to *OVERPRINT* (check in the `ATTRIBUTES` panel) this will cause the colours to mix.
2. You have got `OVERPRINT PREVIEW` turned on (which is why the colour is showing as a mix of red and yellow, i.e. orange).
3. You have `PROOF SETUP` set to `WORKING CMYK` (which is why the colour appears dull, because you can't print bright oranges out of CMYK).

Hopefully one, more or all of the above will help.